# NPM peer dependencies requires 3 different versions of webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, npm-install

I need to have three difference versions of webpack, how do I fix this issue?

> vuetify-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of **webpack@^4.0.0** but none is installed.
>   You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of **webpack@^3.1.0** but none is installed. 
>   You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> webpack-dev-server@2.11.3 requires a peer of **webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0** but none is installed. 
>   You must install peer dependencies yourself.

PS: I was up to now using the latest version 4.28.4 of webpack

Comment: With version 3.0.0, I can't use vuetify-loader. But, I can use  extract-text-webpack-plugin and webpack-dev-server. So, I think I need versions 3.0.0 and 4.0.0 for all three to work

Comment: Latest versions of vuetify-loader and webpack-dev-server work with webpack 4. extract-text-webpack-plugin only works with 3, true, but you can replace it with the mini-css-extract-plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

Comment: I think this is the only option for you, I don't think it's possible to use multiple version of webpack at the same time

Answer (score 0):

According to what I read on SO, I suggest the following procedure.

1. Go for the newest version of `webpack`. The migration guide at https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4/ is pretty well-written.
2. Try make `vuetify-loader` run properly.
3. With `npm remove extract-text-webpack-plugin` get rid of that package since it is deprecated, move forward and use [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) instead.
4. Update `webpack-dev-server` to a version so that works with the current version of `webpack`.